# Facebook Friend List and Birthdays

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I want to **get Users Friend List and their Birthdays from Facebook.**

Can some one help me out as I have read its not possible in recent SDK. If some one could direct me in right path.
Thanks

Comment: now it deprecated how can u do this,

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible anymore since April 30th 2014 with the introduction of the Graph API v2.0. And **no**, there's **no** workaround.